# How to create a workflow app on Sharepoint

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm looking to create a workflow app on Sharepoint. Basically at the top level there's a list of projects. When you click on a project, a list of states is displayed (dev/qa/staging/prod) etc...when a developer finishes their task, they will change the state to QA, and the QA team needs to get a notification.

Is this possible to accomplish in Sharepoint 2007 without any custom webparts?   If not, what's the best way to approach this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do what I wanted to do using SharePoint Designer which is a free download.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2007 supports creation of workflows out of the box MOSS 2007 adds more features on top of basic functionality provided and 2010 versions provide more inprovments.

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386168(v=VS.90).aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386211.aspx to get statred.

Search for "SharePoint workflow" on your favorite search engine for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I found that the easiest way to do this is by doing it from SharePoint Designer which is a free download.